# Unsupported SVG filters hide shapes

Tags: svg, svg-filters

In Edge, if you apply an unsupported filter like `feDropShadow`, the shape is not rendered.

I've also observed this behavior in Chrome for any other unsupported filter. Any workaround?

```html
<svg width='250' height='250' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <!-- Unsupported filter -->
      <feUnsupportedFilter/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle fill="cornflowerblue" filter="url(#filter)" cx="50" cy="35" r="20"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The workaround is not to use unsupported filters. You probably know, but feDropShadow is a shorthand anyway and you can build it yourself. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#feDropShadowElement

Comment: I know, but I prefer the graceful degradation approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you add any other supported filter, the shape will render correctly.

```html
<svg width='250' height='250' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <!-- Supported filter -->
      <feOffset/>
      <!-- Unsupported filter -->
      <feUnsupportedFilter/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle fill="cornflowerblue" filter="url(#filter)" cx="50" cy="35" r="20"/>
</svg>
```